# Without using var, what is the way to invalidate a static value in Scala and set it again to new value later

Tags: scala, cassandra

I have made a factory method which should either start a database (`cassandra`) and connect to it or should return an existing session. The connection to the database is static field.

```
class EmbeddedCassandraManager {

  def getCassandra() = {
    if(EmbeddedCassandraManager.cassandraConnection.isDefined) //return existing instance
      {
        (EmbeddedCassandraManager.testCassandra,EmbeddedCassandraManager.cassandraConnection)
      }
     else {
      EmbeddedCassandraManager.startCassandra()
    }
  }
    
  def closeCassandra() = {

    EmbeddedCassandraManager.closeCassandra()
  }
}

object  EmbeddedCassandraManager {
  val factory = new EmbeddedCassandraFactory
//can I do the logic without using var?

  var (testCassandra,cassandraConnection) = startCassandra()

  def closeCassandra() = {
    cassandraConnection.get.close()
    cassandraConnection = None
    testCassandra.stop()
  }

  def startCassandra():(Cassandra,Option[CassandraConnection]) = {
    val testCassandra = factory.create()
    testCassandra.start()
    val cassandraConnectionFactory:DefaultCassandraConnectionFactory = new DefaultCassandraConnectionFactory();

    val localCassandraConnection:Option[CassandraConnection] = try{
      val connection = cassandraConnectionFactory.create(testCassandra)
      Some(connection)
    }catch{
      case exception:Throwable => {
        throw exception
      }
    }
    this.cassandraConnection = localCassandraConnection

    (testCassandra,this.cassandraConnection)
  }
}
```

The only way I am able to create the logic is by using a `var` for the `cassandraConnection`. Is there a pattern I can use to avoid using `var`?

In one of the test, I have to stop `cassandra` to test that the connection doesn't get established if database isn't running. This makes the existing connection stale. Without `var`, I am not able to set the value to `None` to invalidate the connection and set it to new value once the database connection is established again.

What is the functional way to create such logic? I need static value of connection so that only one connection is created and I want a way to check that the value is not stale.

Comment: Hey, I never got any feedback from you. Did you manage to work it out? Have you perhaps tried using the `State`?

Comment: I am so sorry, quite rude of me to have gone silent. To be honest, I started facing some other issues with the database which diverted my attention. I'll get back soon on this. My apologies again.

Comment: No worries! I was just wondering if you found my answer useless.

Comment: from the 1st look, I think the answer is quite the opposite of that :)

Answer (score 1):

Mutability is often unavoidable, because it is an inherent property of the systems we build. However, that doesn't mean that we have to use mutable variables in our code.

There are usually two main ways that you can deal with situations that involve mutable state:

1. Push the mutable state to a repository outside of your program.

Typical examples of this are "standard" database (if state needs to be persisted) and in-memory storage (if state exists for the duration of your program's lifecycle). Whenever you would fetch a value from such storage, you would treat it as an immutable value. Mutability still exists, but not inside your program, which makes it easier to reason about.

Some people criticize this line of thinking by saying "you are not solving anything, you're just making it some else's problem", and that's true actually. We are letting the database handle the mutability for us. Why not? It's what database is designed to do. Besides, main problem with mutability is reasoning about it, and we are not going to reason about internal implementation of the database. So pushing the mutability from one of our services to another is indeed like throwing the hot potato around, but pushing it to an external system that's designed for it is completely fine.

However, all that being said, it doesn't help your case, because it's not really elegant to store database connection objects in an external storage. Which takes me to point number two.

2. Use state monad.

If the word "monad" raises some flags for you, pretend I said "use `State`" (it's quite a simple concept actually, no big words needed). I will be using the implementation of `State` available in the [Cats library](https://typelevel.org/cats/), but it exists in other FP libraries as well.

`State` is a function from some existing state to a new state and some produced value:

```
S => (S, V)
```

By going from an existing state to a new state, we achieve the "mutation of state".

**Example 1:**

Here's some code that uses an integer state which gets incremented by one and produces a string value every time the state changes:

```
import cats.data.State

val s: State[Int, String] = State((i: Int) => (i + 1, s"Value: $i"))

val program = for {
  produced1 <- s
  _ = println(produced1) // Value: 42
  produced2 <- s
  _ = println(produced2) // Value: 43
  produced3 <- s
  _ = println(produced3) // Value: 44
} yield "Done."

program.run(42).value
```

That's the gist of it.

**Example 2:**

For completeness, here's a bigger example which demonstrates a use case similar to yours.

First, let's introduce a simplified model of `CassandraConnection` (this is just for the sake of example; real object would come from the Cassandra library, so no mutability would exist in our own code).

```
class CassandraConnection() {
  var isOpen: Boolean = false
  def connect(): Unit = isOpen = true
  def close(): Unit = isOpen = false
}
```

How should we define the state? Mutable object is obviously the `CassandraConnection`, and the result value which will be used in for-comprehension could be a simple `String`.

```
import cats.data.State

type DbState = State[CassandraConnection, String]
```

Now let's define some functions for manipulating the state using an existing `CassandraConnection` object.

```
val openConnection: DbState = State(connection => {
  if (connection.isOpen) {
    (connection, "Already connected.")
  } else {
    val newConnection = new CassandraConnection()
    newConnection.connect()
    (newConnection, "Connected!")
  }
})

val closeConnection: DbState = State(connection => {
  connection.close()
  (connection, "Closed!")
})

val checkConnection: DbState =
  State(connection => {
    if (connection.isOpen) (connection, "Connection is open.")
    else (connection, "Connection is closed.")
  })
```

And finally, let's play with these functions in the main program:

```
val program: DbState =
  for {
    log1 <- checkConnection
    _ = println(log1) // Connection is closed.
    log2 <- openConnection
    _ = println(log2) // Connected!
    log3 <- checkConnection
    _ = println(log3) // Connection is open.
    log4 <- openConnection
    _ = println(log4) // Already connected.
    log5 <- closeConnection
    _ = println(log5) // Closed!
    log6 <- checkConnection
    _ = println(log6) // Connection is closed.
  } yield "Done."

program.run(new CassandraConnection()).value
```

I know this is not exact code that you could copy/paste into your project and have it work nicely, but I wanted to give a slightly more general answer that might be a bit easier to understand for other readers. With some playing around, I'm sure you can shape it into your own solution. As long as your main program is a for-comprehension on the `State` level, you can easily open and close your connections and (re)use the same connection objects.

What did we really achieve with this solution? Why is this better than just having a mutable `CassandraConnection` value?

One big thing is that we achieve *referential transparency*, which is why this pattern fits into functional programming paradigm nicely, and standard mutability doesn't. Since this answer is already getting a bit long, I will point you towards [Cats documentation](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/state.html) which explains the whole thing in more detail and demonstrates the benefit of using `State` very nicely.